# Executing Java Class from Python and grab stdout

Tags: python, java, jar

so I am fairly new to Java, and I wrote up a class that uses a library from a jar file and outputs its results.

As this will be part of a bigger project, combining multiple languages, there will be a wrapper script in Python that calls each module (my Java Class in this case), gets the output in a String variable and uses this string in further execution.
When writing the Java Class I always tested it with the "Test Runner for Java" Extension in VSCode.

The way I now execute the Java Class from Python feels kind of hacky, but I did not find another way of doing it, because I don't really understand the concept of classpath I think.

I make the OS change the directory to the where the .class file is located and execute the java command in the terminal with the needed parameters and get the stdout with subporcess.communicate. This is something I found here on Stackoverflow.

Is there a better way of doing it? Can I compile my Java class with the jar-library included, such that I don't have to specify the classpath in every execution?

My Python Code:

```
def execute_java(parameter):
    current_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("./path/to/project/src")
    cmd = ["java", "-cp", "../lib/external_lib.jar:", "My_class", parameter]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
    os.chdir(current_path)
    
    return stdout
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the class uses a class in the jar file you'll always need to provide the jar file as you are doing.  Cannot Java compile that jar or it's classes into your calling class.  The classpath on the java command only tells Java where to find classes during the startup and runtime of the class you invoke on the command line (assuming that class is specified in `parameter`).

Comment: @dan Ok, got it. I had a small error in the snippet. Parameter is actually the parameter the Java class gets from the Python wrapper. The class name is fixed as "My_class".

Comment: The rest of it looks good.  Not sure you really need to change directories as your code is doing.  So long as your classpath is correct, relative paths or absolute, it should find your `My_class` and the jar file.  Don't know of a better way to connect the input/output streams than what you're already doing.